# android viewpager with fragments using FragmentPageAdapter dynamic add, remove

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, fragmentpageradapter

I have an application with tabhost and viewpager.
I have one tab, fragment as fixed.
I have to add tab,fragments dynamically on click radio button in radiogroup from the first fragment.

MyPagerAdapter class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    FragmentManager fm;

    public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
        return fragments;
    }

    public void setFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    public MyViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeFragments() {
        try {
            List<Fragment> newList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
            Fragment general = fragments.get(0);
            newList.add(general);           
            this.fragments.clear();
            this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
            this.fragments = newList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeItemFromFrament(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        try {
            try {
                container.removeViewAt(position);
                ((ViewPager) container).setCurrentItem(position - 1);               
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MyPagerFragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyViewPageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static View mView;

    public static final MyViewPageFragment newInstance(int layoutId) {
        MyViewPageFragment f = new MyViewPageFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("layout", layoutId);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int layout = getArguments().getInt("layout");
        try {
            mView = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return mView;
    }

}
```

Im trying to add fragments to adapter like this:

```
Fragment fragment = MyViewPageFragment.newInstance(R.layout.tab_content_layout);
((MyViewPageAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter()).addFragment(fragment);
```

**My Problem:**
On first time, the pages are added properly, after remove all views(except first fragment) and trying to add another set of tabs, fragments the views are not visible and the getSupportFragmentmanager.getFragments().size() is incorrect.

I tried to remove the views from viewpager with fragment manager

```
FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove((Fragment) object);
trans.commit();
```

After adding tabs, fragments on pagescrolled the getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments.get(arg0) returns null.

**Note:**
I have to maintain the state of the first fragment, so FragmentStatePagerAdapter and getItemPosition return POSITION_NONE is not acceptable.

Comment: Do you think `this.fragments.clear();
            this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
            this.fragments = newList;` is right? What do you want here?

Comment: Yes, i have to maintain the first fragment, because it is static one. So i get the first one and clear all the fragments and add the first fragment to list again

Comment: you can refer 
http://blog.csdn.net/z13759561330/article/details/40737381

Answer (score 1):

In the same way that you don't specifically call `removeView()` on a `ListView` from a `ListAdapter` to get rid of an item, you don't directly remove a `Fragment` with `FragmentManager` from a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

You have to override `getItemPosition()`, but you have to provide a little more intelligent implementation than just returning `POSITION_NONE` all the time.

If your first fragment never changes, then always return `POSITION_UNCHANGED`  when that fragment is passed to `getItemPosition()`

Think about it as a conversation between you and the `ViewPager`/`FragmentPagerAdapter`. Here's an example:

You: "I need to change the fragments around." (call `notifyDataSetChanged`)

Adapter: "Heads up, I'm going to change everything around now." (callback `startUpdate`)

Adapter: "How many tabs do you want?" (callback `getCount()`)

You: Three.  (return '3')

Adapter: "Okay, what do you want me to do with this first one?" (callback `getItemPosition`)

You: "I want to keep that one right where it is." (return `POSITION_UNCHANGED`)

Adapter: "Great, what about this second one?" (callback `getItemPosition`)

You: "I want to move it to the third tab." (return '2')

Adapter: "All right, what about the third one?" (callback `getItemPosition`)

You: "I want to get rid of that one completely." (return `POSITION_NONE`)

Adapter: "Okay, I have a space for the second tab, what fragment do you want me to use?"  (callback `getItem`)

You: "This one." (return fragment for position == 1)

Adapter: "I'm done changing everything, kthxbye."  (callback `finishUpdate`)

I might not have the order of calls exactly right, but the basic idea is there.

If you need to maintain the state of the fragments that are kicked out, you could override `getItem()` and `destroyItem()` to help you with that:

```
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragmentManager = fm;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // figure out which fragment you want at this position
    Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    // retrieve your savedState from wherever you put it
    fragment.setInitialSavedState(savedState);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
    Fragment.SavedState savedState = mFragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState(fragment)
    // save your fragment state somewhere here
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
```

Your fragments will need to implement `saveState()` and `restoreState()` for this to work.

Comment: I need to maintain the state of newly added fragments till i remove it from fragment list. Because i have edittext in the fragments, if i return POSITION_NONE for non-first fragment, i couldn't get the 2nd and 3rd fragments previous state.

Comment: Updated my answer to include some code for saving/restoring fragment state.

Answer (score 0):

I tried similar requirement as yours with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter which worked fine. May be it could help you.

To add the new fragment:

```
SIZE = SIZE +1;
adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, SIZE-1);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In getItem(), for the "position" create and return the new fragment (I used a switch statement here)

Update the getCount() method to return the new SIZE.

Let me know if you would like me to share the code.